# How to use mobile vision API with TextureView and Camera

Tags: android, android-vision, google-vision, android-textureview

I am using mobile vision API for scanning barcode. I am using `TextureView` to render camera on it. I read this github thread https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/15 it seems mobile vision is not compatible with `TextureView`

I see that `CameraSource` is for `SurfaceView` which is not compatible with `TextureView`, as there is no method to preview frames on `TextureView`. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/CameraSource.html#start(android.view.SurfaceHolder)

I tried to do using below approach and checked that `receiveDetections` is not being called. Does anyone have any idea how can I integrate mobile vision API with `TextureView` and `Camera`.

### MainActivity.java

```
@RuntimePermissions
public class ScanBarcodeActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private TextureView textureView;

    private BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;

    private Camera camera;

    private String TAG = LogUtils.makeLogTag(ScanBarcodeActivity.class);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityScanBarcodeBinding activityScanBarcodeBinding = setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_scan_barcode);

        textureView = activityScanBarcodeBinding.textureView;

        barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).build();

        ScanBarcodeActivityPermissionsDispatcher.requestCameraPermissionWithCheck(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        // NOTE: delegate the permission handling to generated method
        ScanBarcodeActivityPermissionsDispatcher.onRequestPermissionsResult(this, requestCode, grantResults);

        if(permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                initializeCamera();            }
        }
    }

    @NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    void requestCameraPermission() {
        initializeCamera();
    }

    void initializeCamera() {
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                camera = Camera.open();

                /* Set Auto focus */
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
                if(focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)){
                    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                } else
                if(focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)){
                    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                }

                camera.setParameters(parameters);

                try {
                    camera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
                } catch (IOException io) {
                    LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, io.getMessage());
                }
                camera.startPreview();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
                try {
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    camera.release();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

            }
        });

        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

                if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                    LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @OnShowRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    void showRationaleForCamera(final PermissionRequest request) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(R.string.permission_camera_rationale)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_allow, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        request.proceed();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.button_deny, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        request.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

    @OnPermissionDenied(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    void showPermissionDeniedForCamera() {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_camera_denied, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @OnNeverAskAgain(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    void showNeverAskAgainForCamera() {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_camera_never_ask_again, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

The BarcodeReader Vision example uses SurfaceView by defualt for a very simple reason: Compatibility. SurfaceView is available from API Level 1, but TextureView is available from API Level 14.

Luckily, it is possible to create a BarcodeReader that supports both SurfaceView and TextureView, without losing compatibility at all.

I do not remember where exactly, but Google has created a Class based on TextureView that enhances its behabiour preventing stretched images. It is called "AutoFitTextureView" and I have made it for you:

```
public class AutoFitTextureView extends TextureView {
    private int mRatioWidth = 0;
    private int mRatioHeight = 0;

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the aspect ratio for this view. The size of the view will be measured based on the ratio
     * calculated from the parameters. Note that the actual sizes of parameters don't matter, that
     * is, calling setAspectRatio(2, 3) and setAspectRatio(4, 6) make the same result.
     *
     * @param width  Relative horizontal size
     * @param height Relative vertical size
     */
    public void setAspectRatio(int width, int height) {
        if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be negative.");
        }
        mRatioWidth = width;
        mRatioHeight = height;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (0 == mRatioWidth || 0 == mRatioHeight) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
                setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mRatioHeight / mRatioWidth);
            } else {
                setMeasuredDimension(height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight, height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use that new Class instead of SurfaceView on CameraSourcePreview class:

**Take a look at the commented lines that were for SurfaceView**

```
public class CameraSourcePreview extends ViewGroup {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraSourcePreview";

    private Context mContext;
    //private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private AutoFitTextureView mAutoFitTextureView;
    private boolean mStartRequested;
    private boolean mSurfaceAvailable;
    private CameraSource mCameraSource;

    private GraphicOverlay mOverlay;

    public CameraSourcePreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        mStartRequested = false;
        mSurfaceAvailable = false;

        //mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        //mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceCallback());
        //addView(mSurfaceView);
        mAutoFitTextureView = new AutoFitTextureView(context);
        mAutoFitTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        addView(mAutoFitTextureView);
    }

    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    public void start(CameraSource cameraSource) throws IOException, SecurityException {
        if (cameraSource == null) {
            stop();
        }

        mCameraSource = cameraSource;

        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mStartRequested = true;
            startIfReady();
        }
    }

    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    public void start(CameraSource cameraSource, GraphicOverlay overlay) throws IOException, SecurityException {
        mOverlay = overlay;
        start(cameraSource);
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mCameraSource.stop();
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mCameraSource.release();
            mCameraSource = null;
        }
    }

    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    private void startIfReady() throws IOException, SecurityException {
        if (mStartRequested && mSurfaceAvailable) {
            //mCameraSource.start(mSurfaceView.getHolder());
            mCameraSource.start(mAutoFitTextureView);
            if (mOverlay != null) {
                Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
                int min = Math.min(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
                int max = Math.max(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
                if (isPortraitMode()) {
                    // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated by
                    // 90 degrees
                    mOverlay.setCameraInfo(min, max, mCameraSource.getCameraFacing());
                } else {
                    mOverlay.setCameraInfo(max, min, mCameraSource.getCameraFacing());
                }
                mOverlay.clear();
            }
            mStartRequested = false;
        }
    }

    private final TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
            mSurfaceAvailable = true;
            mOverlay.bringToFront();
            try {startIfReady();} catch (IOException e) {Log.e(TAG, "Could not start camera source.", e);}
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {}
        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture texture) {
            mSurfaceAvailable = false;
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture texture) {}
    };

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        int width = 320;
        int height = 240;
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
            if (size != null) {
                width = size.getWidth();
                height = size.getHeight();
            }
        }

        // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated 90 degrees
        if (isPortraitMode()) {
            int tmp = width;
            //noinspection SuspiciousNameCombination
            width = height;
            height = tmp;
        }

        final int layoutWidth = right - left;
        final int layoutHeight = bottom - top;

        // Computes height and width for potentially doing fit width.
        int childWidth = layoutWidth;
        int childHeight = (int)(((float) layoutWidth / (float) width) * height);

        // If height is too tall using fit width, does fit height instead.
        if (childHeight > layoutHeight) {
            childHeight = layoutHeight;
            childWidth = (int)(((float) layoutHeight / (float) height) * width);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); ++i) {
            getChildAt(i).layout(0, 0, childWidth, childHeight);
        }

        try {
            startIfReady();
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Do not have permission to start the camera", se);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not start camera source.", e);
        }
    }

    private boolean isPortraitMode() {
        int orientation = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            return false;
        }
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            return true;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "isPortraitMode returning false by default");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally, you should add a new **start** method to the CameraSource class:

**notice that this new method is called from CameraSourcePreview class**

```
public CameraSource start(AutoFitTextureView textureView) throws IOException {
    synchronized (mCameraLock) {
        if(mCamera != null) {
            return this;
        }

        mCamera = createCamera();
        mCamera.setPreviewTexture(textureView.getSurfaceTexture());
        mCamera.startPreview();

        mProcessingThread = new Thread(mFrameProcessor);
        mFrameProcessor.setActive(true);
        mProcessingThread.start();
    }
    return this;
}
```

Now you have your own BarcodeReader with your TextureView.
I have tested all the code and working on S4 Lollipop and Nexus5 Marshmallow.

Hope helping you!